# SQL WordPress order by date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I think there is error with SQL

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.post_content, wp_terms.name, wp_terms.slug, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_posts
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)
        WHERE ((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category') or (wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy is NULL))
           AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
           AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
           ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date_gmt DESC
           LIMIT 10
           )
           GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
           ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC
           LIMIT 5
```

I'm trying to order the posts by DATE

Comment: What error do you get? Have we to read your mind?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10
           )
    
           GROUP' at line 10

Comment: After the `LIMIT 10` there is an never-opened round bracket